# Issue with possibility to add next item after add and remove item jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi this is a shopping list. I want to add a listitem **works** remove listitem **works** **too** but when I try to add next item there is no adding event.

### Question

How to add item after add/remove listitem?

### Purpose

I want to make add independent from remove (after remove it is possible to add)

### Code

https://jsbin.com/vefiwa/edit?html,output

Comment: solved but new bug comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just use an id as selector instead of the ul tag, for instance : var ul = $('#lv'); in the function whichBtn() should work for you

Comment: this is answer on question or on my answer?

Comment: It's an answer  on the jsbin you provided, when selecting $('ul') you select them all, hence the duplicate on each ul tag, using an id as selector you'll get only what you want

Comment: you're right! I didn't notice but I know about it... thanks a lot, just a minor mistake

Answer (score 0):

solved use `.empty()` instead of `.detach()`

reason: I detached when remove the `<ul>` then wanted to append when adding but I didn't have `<ul>`

**but now when *add->remove->add* I have weird behaviour it adds additionally listitem on the top of page** see updated jsbin https://jsbin.com/vefiwa/edit?html,js,output